# How to use bracket notation in Dart object?

Tags: dart

in javascript,we can get array length by ArrayName["length"] instead of ArrayName.length.
but it not work in Dart...
I want get object properties by string.
Is there a way to do this in Dart without using Map?

Comment: Can you describe your reason for you want this feature? Maybe we can find some alternative solution which will work for you.

Comment: When using Map, autocomplete does not work for the <string>propertyName in the bracket. On the other hand, if I use an Dart object that can use dot notation, property autocomplete will work in VS Code, but I can not get the property dynamically. JS objects that can do both are great.

Comment: In most cases, you should not use `Map` as a kind of data structure to have different kind of data since that cannot be made typesafe (since Dart does not care at compile time what keys are inside the `Map` when defined). You should instead make classes which can specific the exact type for each property and therefore typesafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Dart. Dart is a compiled language and makes optimizations based on what methods are actually used in e.g. classes. So by allowing accessing fields and methods by random strings, it would not be possible to predict what fields/methods are actually used and therefore it needs to provide access to every field/method available which would increase the size of the compiled application by a lot.

If you are running directly on the Dart VM, you can use `dart:mirrors` to provide reflection on your objects, but that is only possible since you are running the source code directly with the Dart VM, and it can therefore reflect over the source.

But after a Dart program is compiled, the compiler will have removed the parts of the source code which are never going to be used.